# How do I prevent users from running applications using invalid shortcuts?

Tags: c#, .net

I work in an environment where my department maintains various in-house applications used by our company users with varying computer skill level.

We've had numerous problems in the past where users copy shortcuts from one machine to another, or worse, use shortcuts to applications they've had emailed to them from other users.

For the most part, it doesn't really cause any problems. However, we do get support tickets occasionally because someone is trying to run a shortcut where the path is incorrect, or points to another machine on the network and loads the wrong files.

We're working on some new applications, and I'd love to find a method to prevent that from happening.

My initial thought is to somehow find a way to read how the program was executed and somehow backtrack to the location of the shortcut and find out where it was running from. At that point I could validate the shortcut and/or restrict shortcut. i.e. somehow force the program to be launched directly by exe or from a desktop shortcut only. I don't really know how to find out the shortcut-that-called-the-exe-path however...

Thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: You mean you want to intercept/change how Explorer.exe handles .lnk shortcuts?

Comment: ClickOnce deployment might help...

Comment: Not so much to intercept/change, more so to see what happened (ok, maybe intercept?) and make a decision based off of that. Or... some other method, I'm open to ideas.

Comment: ClickOnce would help, but, a big part of the problem is that the users tend to think they can "install" programs on new machines by emailing the shortcuts to each other instead of waiting for the correct person to do so.

Comment: “Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the Universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the Universe is winning.”- Rich Cook This may not be an answer or help, but it does seem to apply.

Comment: If the shortcut was "invalid" they would already not be able to run the application.

Comment: This really sounds more like an administration problem than a programming problem. You can have diagnostics that make the program show its command line, the current executable directory, and also the current working directory (or the startup working directory). If those are incorrect, then it's likely that the user used an "invalid" shortcut. If you tell users to use only the shortcut you gave them, then you could have the program check that shortcut file (one would assume you have it in a standard place).

Comment: Start with how would the program know it was launched by a shortcut.

Comment: @N4TKD - Love the quote, it definitely applies and does make me think I might be chasing after nothing. Or, maybe I'm just gaining a lead against the bigger idiots? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation would be left up to you, but a great preliminary check would be to examine the path property of the shortcut file. For example, if someone emailed another user a shortcut and had it placed on the desktop, the path would contain the user of the person who emailed the shortcut rather than the current user. Other than that you could try:

```
File.Exists(shortcutPath);
```

You could bundle up some simple rules like these into a console application that recursively checks all the shortcuts on a machine and if they are invalid, delete them.